# Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll: The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, entity-framework

The software I am debugging is a console application, using .net Framework 4.7.2.
In visual studio I have installed the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll v14.0.1016.290 via Nuget.

**Error Message:**

Error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, **Version=10.0.0.0**, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

In **packages.config** I have added this line:

```
<packages>
    <package id="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" version="14.0.1016.290" targetFramework="net472" />
</packages>
```

In **app.config** I have deleted this line, and it has added itself back again:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

I also have msvcr120.dll and SqlServerSpatial140.dll in the base directory.

I cannot figure out why the software is trying to load v10 of sqlServer.Types?
What am I missing?
Thank you for your help.